# node-compass not compiling scss

Tags: node.js, express, compass-sass

Using node-compass 2.3.0 on express 4, I did this:

```
app.use(require('node-compass')({
    logging: true,
    css: path.join(__dirname, 'public/css'),
    project: path.join(__dirname, 'public/scss')
}));
```

and nothing happens, no errors. Any ideas why?

Comment: Have you checked if the directory paths are correct?

Answer (score 0):

Accodring to the [docs](https://github.com/nathggns/node-compass#css):

> **project** : The location where all your assets are store
>
> **css** : The folder ***inside*** the project to output css into.
>
> **sass** : The folder ***inside*** the project to find sass in.

```
project: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
css: 'css',
sass: 'scss'
```